# need to set :references option for association :contacts when schema has no primary key

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have following schemas:

```
  @primary_key false
  schema "companies" do
    field :number,         :integer, primary_key: true, read_after_writes: true
    field :name,           :string
    field :street,         :string
    has_many :contacts,    Busiket.Contact

    timestamps
  end


  schema "contacts" do

    field :firstname,     :string
    field :lastname,      :string

    belongs_to :company, Busiket.Company, foreign_key: :company, references: :number, type: :integer

    timestamps

  end
```

I've got following error:

```
** (ArgumentError) need to set :references option for association :contacts when schema has no primary key
    lib/ecto/association.ex:329: Ecto.Association.Has.struct/3
    lib/ecto/schema.ex:1434: Ecto.Schema.association/5
    lib/ecto/schema.ex:1249: Ecto.Schema.__has_many__/4
    web/models/company.ex:18: (module)
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:670: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
```

The migration looks:

```
create table(:companies, primary_key: false) do

  add :number,             :serial, primary_key: true
  add :name,               :string
  add :street,             :string
  add :zipcode,            :integer
  add :location,           :string
  add :phone,              :integer
  add :company_class,      references(:companies_classes, column: :code, type: :integer)
  add :country_iso,        references(:countries_codes, column: :iso, type: :string)
  add :email,              :string
  add :password_hash,      :string

  timestamps
end
execute "select setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('companies', 'number'), 999999)"
create unique_index(:companies, [:name, :email])

create table(:contacts) do

  add :firstname,      :string
  add :lastname,       :string
  add :title,          :string
  add :email,          :string
  add :password_hash,  :string

  add :company, references(:companies, column: :number, type: :integer, on_delete: :delete_all)

  timestamps
end
create unique_index(:contacts, [:email])
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `has_many :contacts, Busiket.Contact, references: :number` in `companies` schema.

Comment: Then I've got following error `ArgumentError) foreign_key :company must be distinct from corresponding association name`.

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to change either the name of the `company` column or the name of the loaded association in the `contacts` schema. The database column will contain an integer and the association name will contain the loaded `Company` struct.